# Time Dataframe with end start columns to 10min range Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe where the start and end time of a description are in columns. The description is in another column.

I'm trying to transform the dataset into a 10min range dataframe. In the output dataframe the start and end date are chosen. If there is not data should be nan

As example:

```
start_date = 15/09/2020 14:00:00
end_date = 16/09/2020 23:00:00
```

Data DataFrame

```
     start_time              end_time           info

15/09/2020 14:35:54       15/09/2020 15:05:48     A                
15/09/2020 15:54:05       16/09/2020 02:15:22     B 
16/09/2020 21:17:10       16/09/2020 22:15:04     A 
...
```

Test DataFrame

```
      timestamp          info

15/09/2020 14:00:00       nan   
15/09/2020 14:10:00       nan
15/09/2020 14:20:00       nan
15/09/2020 14:30:00       A
15/09/2020 14:40:00       A
15/09/2020 14:50:00       A
15/09/2020 15:00:00       A
15/09/2020 15:10:00       A
15/09/2020 15:20:00       nan
15/09/2020 15:30:00       nan
15/09/2020 15:40:00       nan
15/09/2020 15:50:00       B
15/09/2020 16:00:00       B
15/09/2020 16:10:00       B
15/09/2020 16:20:00       B
...
```

So far i've done:

```
data['timestampStart'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestampStart'])
data['timestampEnd'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestampEnd'])

range_time = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='10min')
test= pd.DataFrame()
test['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(range_time)

for index, row in data.iterrows():
    if test['timestamp'] > data['timestampStart'] & test['timestamp'] < data['timestampEnd']:
        test['description'] = data['description']
    else:
        test['description'] == np.nan
```

I get an error in the if statement:
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'Timestamp' and 'Timestamp'

but i got stuck in how to sorted it out. Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I think your error comes form the fact that you need parentheses around multiple conditions.

if (test['timestamp'] > data['timestampStart']) & (test['timestamp'] < data['timestampEnd']):

Comment: thanks @yashar but when i apply it it returns: 
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Comment: Oh, I see. That's because you are iterating over data, and not the test, so in each loop it tries to compare whole column (Series) of test with a single value in data. I have a suggestion that I will put in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def check_date(s,d):
    if len(d[(d.timestampStart<s)&(d.timestampEnd>s)]) > 0:
        return d[(d.timestampStart<s)&(d.timestampEnd>s)].iloc[0]['info']
    else:
        return None

test['description'] = test.timestamp.apply(lambda x: check_date(x, data))
```

This will use each row of the test dataframe, to find out if there are any matching values found on data dataframe. Its not very elegant, but it seems to be working.

**Update: Method 2**

You can change the main data frame to achieve what you are looking for

```
data['start_base'] = data.start_time.apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=int(x.minute/10)*10, second=0))

data['timestamp'] = data.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x.start_base, end=x.end_time,freq='10min'), axis=1)

new_data = data[['timestamp','info']].explode('length')
```

We are essentially writing down the 10 minute intervals between each 'start'/'end' pair, and then putting the in a single column by df.explode().
Then you can merge this to the 'test' data frame, to get all the time slots as you want.

```
test = test.merge(new_data, on='timestamp', how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, its quite slow. Do you have any suggestion about how to speed it up?

Comment: I have updated the answer with another suggestion, I think this would be much faster. The problem with the first solution is feeding the whole 'data' dataframe to each row on apply. As I mentioned, it was not a very elegant solution. :)